# How can I do an Ember.js computed property on an Ember Data model based on an async relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember Data model and I'm trying to do a computed property based on properties of an async hasMany relationship. For some reason, it never seems to recompute. How can I do this properly?

The code:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    splits: DS.hasMany('split', { async: true }),
    amount: Ember.reduceComputed('splits.@each.amount', {
        initialValue: 0,
        addedItem: function(accValue, split) { return accValue + split.get('amount'); },
        removedItem: function(accValue, split) { return accValue - split.get('amount'); }
    })
    /* Neither of these work either.
    amount: Ember.computed.sum('splits.@each.amount') // This doesn't work
    amount: Ember.computed('splits.@each.amount', function() {
        return this.get('splits').reduce(function(pValue, split) {
            return pValue + split.get('amount');
        }, 0);
    })
    */
});
```

The failing test (Expected `1350`, Got `0`):

```
import { test, moduleForModel } from 'ember-qunit';
import Transaction from 'my-app/models/transaction';

moduleForModel('transaction', 'Unit - Transaction Model', {
    needs: ['model:split']
});

test('amount', function() {
    var transaction = this.subject();
    var store = this.store();
    transaction.get('splits').addObjects([
        store.createRecord('split', { amount: 250 }),
        store.createRecord('split', { amount: 1000 })
    ]);
    equal(transaction.get('amount'), 1250);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hasMany property is async, therefore it is a promise and its value must be accesible with the **then** method.

```
transaction.get('splits').then(function(splits) {

  split = store.createRecord('split', { amount: 250 }),
  splits.pushObject(split);

  split = store.createRecord('split', { amount: 1000 })
  splits.pushObject(split);

});
```

Comment: So without `DataBoundPromise`s, would I be able to use `amount` in a template?

Comment: @Kerrick, I added a third option to make it work with templates. I think, this is what you are looking for. I guess, this is the case that DataBoundPromise makes it work out of the box.

Comment: Actually, I just tried it out and using `{{amount}}` in a template without any of the `amountPromise` or `PromiseProxyMixin` seems to work just fine, making Point 1 false and Point 3 unnecessary. It looks like the entire problem was what you mentioned in Point 2 about using `.then` in the test.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Using splits.@each ensures the property be computed based on the loaded items and handle correctly the result.

Answer (score 3):

Hehe, I typed up a fairly long answer, only to realize what you were doing wrong, and then got a good laugh at myself for not realizing it. :) It's been a long time since I've used Ember-Data, but here's what I've got.

First of all, this has nothing to do with promises. Ember-Data hasMany relationships return `PromiseArray` objects. `PromiseArray` extends from `ArrayProxy`. And `ArrayProxy` is a way to populate and array asynchronously, while still being able to bind to it immediately. `ArrayProxy` does **not** specify how you should populate the array, therefore, the fact that `PromiseArray` uses a promise is irrelevant. Bind to an `ArrayProxy` like you would any other array. When the content changes (for whatever reason), your bindings will update.

Now that we have that out of the way, what you're doing wrong is using the Ember computed helpers wrong. For instance, `Ember.comptued.sum` is supposed to add an array of numbers. Something like this:

```
numbers: [1,2,3,4,5],
sum: Ember.computed.sum('numbers')
```

Ember takes care of the `@each` and all of that nonsense for you. But you don't have straight numbers, you have objects. So you need to use `Ember.reduceComputed` (or something similar). You were using that, but you were using the wrong key. You tacked on the `.@each.amount`, which isn't what Ember was expecting. So Ember was silently failing because behind the scenes, it was watching the `splits.@each.amount.@each` property. If you wanted to use `reduceComputed`, you would do something like this:

```
amount: Ember.reduceComputed('splits', { ... })
```

But I've never used `reduceComputed`, and I like to keep it simple, so try this:

```
amount: function() {
    return this.get('splits').reduce(function(sum, split) {
        return sum + split.get('amount');
    }, 0);
}.property('splits.@each.amount')
```

Sorry for the long answer, but I wanted to explain my solution rather than just giving it. It's early, so if I screwed up some syntax, let me know. But I think you should get the main idea. :)

EDIT: I put together a small JSBin to kind of simulate what you're doing. You can find it [here](http://jsbin.com/zocinahe/2/edit). You'll see that the `objects` property is an unresolved `PromiseArray`, just like you would get from an Ember-Data hasMany relationship. As soon as you click the 'resolve' button, the promise resolves, the `ArrayProxy` updates, and your computed total updates as well.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that using `Ember.computed.sum` was wrong here. However, after trying your computed property (which is functionally equivalent to the third attempt in my question) it still did not work. It seems the true missing piece of the puzzle was what @ppcano brought up about using `.then` to access the splits in the test.

So while you definitely get an upvote for pointing out the bad usage of `Ember.computed.sum`, I must award the answer and bounty to @ppcano because your answer on its own does not help the test pass.

Comment: Also, the `reduceComputed` with the dependent key `'splits.@each.amount'` does seem to work once I use `.then`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
DS.Model.extend({
    splits: DS.hasMany('split', { async: true }),
    splitAmountAry:Ember.computed.mapBy('amount'),
    amount:Ember.computed.sum('splitAmountAry')
})
```